# Формулы в Excel

Tags: формулы, excel

Помогите, пожалуйста, для excel написать формулу расчета функции: для расчета приближенного значения факториала числа `n` по формуле Стирлинга, используя функции СТЕПЕНЬ, EXP, КОРЕНЬ, ПИ.

Вот такая формула (только, конечно без `o` малого в скобке):

[image]

Для `n` от 1 до 20.

Comment: Конечно, поможем, айооо. Какие вопросы, что непонятно, что не получается?

Comment: Функция для меня пока что сложная, не знаю, как быть с факториалом и складывать сложные функции между собой...

Comment: Ничего складывать не нужно. Пишем в одну ячейку значение n, в другую "="(знак "равно" - начало формулы), открываем справку по функциям, которые Вы перечислили... Дальше все просто: исходная формула есть, функции Вы изучили. Вперед!

Comment: @Snaut попробуйте писать формулу постепенно.

Comment: =C2^C2*EXP((-C2))*(2*ПИ()*C2)^(1/2)*(1+0) вроде правильно... а как сюда вставить КОРЕНЬ и т.п.

Comment: @Snaut Не вижу знаков умножения. А корень аналогично экспоненте записывается (которая EXP)